# Mysql data range displaying odd results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that sets the data range but the results are not following the query, I can set a single value with no issue, but when I set the range it grabs all.  The range is between 2 and 50 and it pulls the value of 3000. here is the code:

```
 SELECT SUM(datamb) AS tiera FROM maindata2 WHERE dataplan BETWEEN '2' AND '50' and     email='email@email'
```

Comment: may be you have to use order by email, what is your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2 and 50 are in quotes, you imply calculating `BETWEEN` in an *alphanumeric* manner.

Remove the quotes, like so:

```
SELECT SUM(datamb) AS tiera FROM maindata2 
WHERE dataplan BETWEEN 2 AND 50 and email='email@email'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're trying to get a range between two strings '2' and '50'. You should try using `BETWEEN 2 AND 50`.